# In C# is it possible to instantiate a class with a value?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, instantiation

In C# is it possible to instantiate a class with a value? That is to say if a class contains an array, is it possible to create a class that you pass the length of the desired array when the class is instantiated?

Comment: Sure, why not. have you looked at [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - The reason I downvoted is because this doesn't show any research effort. Personally I don't think a plain "is this possible?" question is a very well formulated question if it doesn't show any effort on behalf of the asker (a reason which is one of the tool tips of the downvote arrow). Figured mentioning my reasoning might be nice for OP to know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The most obvious way is to use the constructor of the class:

```
class X
{
    public int[] MyArray
    {
         get;
         set;
    }

    public X(int arrayLength)
    {
         MyArray = new int[arrayLength];
    }
}
```

You can now instantiate it with:

```
X myX = new X(5);
```

You can also instantiate a class using it properties:

```
class X
{
    public int[] MyArray
    {
         get;
         set;
    }

    public int ArrayLength
    {
        set
        {
             MyArray = new int[value];
        }
    }
}
```

And call it as follows:

```
X myX = new X { ArrayLength = 5};
```

I would go with the first option...

Comment: _pass the *length* of the desired array_ . Not the array itself

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I couldn't find it with the Googles. I really had never seen it before but I thought it was possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string[] _myArray;

    public MyClass(int arrayLength)
    {
        _myArray = new string[arrayLength];
    }
}


var myClass = new MyClass(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the the length as constructor parameter. The constructor looks like a method having the same name as the class, but without return type (not even `void`).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int arrayLength)
    {
        MyArray = new string[arrayLength];
    }

    public string[] MyArray { get; }
}
```

This solution uses a getter only property. You can initialize it in the constructor or with a property initializer, but once the object has been created, it read-only.

You can create a `MyClass` object like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass(10);
string firstElementOfArray = obj.MyArray[0];
string lastElementOfArray = obj.MyArray[9];
```

But please, choose better names than `MyClass` or `MyArray`. Real names must be informative. A Class could be named `Student` or `Vehicle` or `Invoice`. The array could be named `Grades`, `Passengers` or `InvoiceLineItems`.

But depending on your requirements, the array could just be a private field, not accessible from outside the class.